# Rails multi-tenancy, scopes, class variables and thread safety

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, concurrency, thread-safety, multi-tenant, scopes

### Short Version

Are class variables thread-safe for the duration of a controller action?

### Long Version

I'm writing a Rails 3 app that implements multi-tenancy using a single database schema with `tenant_id` columns in each table to identify to whom the data belongs.

Naturally I need a way to scope all queries that are run on the database to ensure that access to data is properly isolated per-tenant.

Several people have suggested achieving this by always accessing the database through the `tenant` instance, e.g.:

```
current_tenant.associate_collection.where(...)
```

etc.

However, since multi-tenancy is an architectural concern (not a business domain concern), I'd prefer to keep this as transparent to the model as possible by setting it up the scope globally. It's also much DRYer.

I've found I can do this using the [multitenant gem](https://github.com/wireframe/multitenant) and around_filters:

```
class ApplicationController
  around_filter do
    Multitenant.with_tenant current_tenant
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

This manipulates the `default_scope` of the appropriate models so that all data access is automatically scoped to the current tenant.

This works great in development, but I have concerns about thread safety. `Multitenant.with_tenant` preserves the `current_tenant` reference in a class variable.

The question is **can I rely on the integrity of that variable while the controller action is on the stack?** or could it be corrupted by another request?

Also, what’s a good source on general concurrency issues in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of duration, and there isn't anything special about a controller that makes it an atomic (uninterruptible) sequence of code. Thread safety is about understanding locks, synchronization, and the thread scheduler.

I don't think your question is even Rails specific in this case. In a general sense, thread safety is achieved through locking data while a write is happening, and unlocking it when the write is finished. It's very similar database locking mechanisms, if you're familiar with those.

For a good reference that focuses on Ruby, I would go here: http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_threads.html

For more info about the concept the thread safety (threads run at the OS level, after all, so it's more about understanding how thread safety works in any program), I would go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: Thanks normalocity, appreciated ~ but the question *is* indeed specific to Rails. I'm asking if the class variables in question are synchronized while the controller action is running. In any case I guess you can create the lock yourself, but it would be useful to know how Rails handles this by default.

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit too broad, I'll agree. Controllers are not synchronized automatically. You would have to put a lock around it yourself.